# 2.2 Scheduled Timer Returns "View Controller has No Member..."

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I am at my wit's end here trying to figure out how to get this NSTimer to work. Pasting my entire code for clarity's sake. The important part is bolded.

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var outerCircle: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var innerCircle: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var instructionLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    var timer: NSTimer!


    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.runTimedCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    func runTimedCode() {


        UIView.animateWithDuration(5, delay:0, options:[], animations: {
            //Inhale
            self.innerCircle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3.5, 3.5)
            self.instructionLabel.text = "Inhale"

            }, completion: { finish in
                //Exhale
                UIView.animateWithDuration(5, delay:0, options:[], animations: {

                    self.innerCircle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)
                    self.instructionLabel.text = "Exhale"
                    }, completion: nil)
        })

    }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

**I want what is in the "runTimedCode()" to run every 10 seconds. I am currently getting an error on:**

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.runTimedCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

The error says "Type 'ViewController' has no member 'runTimedCode'.

When I take ViewController. out, I get a different error: Use of local variable 'runTimedCode' before its declaration.

And finally, when I move that line to the bottom of the code, I get "Argument of '#selector' refers to a method that is not exposed to Objective-C.

I feel like I have honestly tried everything to get this timer to work. I have looked at every thread imaginable. Do I have some kind of fundamental misunderstanding of how the timer functions?

Comment: Everyone was right..it was because of the placement of a function within another function. I am really new to this, so I apologize for such an amateur mistake. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone is right, you defined your `runTimedCode` function inside your `viewDidLoad` so it's in the wrong scope. Also you should avoid nesting animations inside the completion blocks. Try using the code I have prepared for you below.

```
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var outerCircle: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var innerCircle: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var instructionLabel: UILabel!

    // MARK: Properties

    var timer: NSTimer?

    // MARK: Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5,
            target: self,
            selector: #selector(timerDidFinish),
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true
        )
    }

    // MARK: NSTimer

    func timerDidFinish() {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(5, delay: 0, options: [.Autoreverse], animations: {
            self.innerCircle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3.5, 3.5)
            self.instructionLabel.text = "Inhale"
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I LOVE YOU. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you've put `func runTimedCode() {...}` *inside* another function, `viewDidLoad`. You can't do that. Put it at the top level of your view controller.

Answer (score 2):

Your viewcontroller doesn't have a `runTimedCode` method.

You're declaring it inside the `viewDidLoad` function, you should move it outside.